# Why won't php5-fpm start?

Tags: linux, php, php-fpm

I've just installed php-fpm 5.6.8 but it won't start - `start php5-fpm` gives me a `Job failed to start` message. I've found several people with simalar problems, but the none of the answers seem to work for me.

One solution I tried was using the command in `/etc/init/php5-fpm.conf`, which was `/usr/sbin/php5-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` - This returned `-bash: /usr/sbin/php5-fpm: No such file or directory` - I'm thinking that's a big clue as to what may be wrong. Attempting to run in foreground mode with `php5-fpm -y /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` tells me `The program 'php5-fpm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm`. Doing that returns the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php5-fpm is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 webmin : Depends: libnet-ssleay-perl but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libauthen-pam-perl but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libio-pty-perl but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: apt-show-versions but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Can anyone figure out what's going on here? I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 by the way.

Comment: Do what it told you to do.

Comment: You mean `apt-get -f install`? Tried that. Didn't solve it.

Comment: This question is about using a web hosting control panel (webmin), which is off-topic on Serverfault.

Comment: It actually wasn't, I'd given up on getting webmin working at that point, and was trying to get php5-fpm working. `apt-get -f install` did get webmin working, however, and reinstalling php5-fpm through that finally got it working, though I was hoping to figure out how to do it through command line.